# How to solve Code: :Blocks OpenGL problem

Tags: c++, opengl, codeblocks, glut, glu

I'm using Code: :Blocks for running OpenGL projects and codes. To cut to the chase, I tried to move the file glut32.dll to the directory C:\Windows\System32 and it was **Successfully** copied and pasted, but whenever I try to search for the file it can't be found, even when I scroll down alphabetically to gl files and couldn't find it. I tried to re copy and paste the file and when I tried to paste it in the same directory I was given the option to replace the **Already existing file**, which means that the file already exists in that folder. I tried the cmd command (while running in administrator) `regsvr32 glut32.dll` and it gave me the following message:

[image]

I pasted the file in this location **too** `C:\WINDOWS\SysWOW64`, and the same happended
and when I neglected it and started running the code, this error occured:

[image]

I'm using:

- Windows 10 64-bits
- Code: :Blocks 20.03

I can't run any of my OpenGL projects.
Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score -1):

What version is your operating system? 64-bit or 32-bit?
64-bit:copy glut32.dll to C:\WINDOWS\SysWOW64
32-bit:copy glut32.dll to C:\WINDOWS\system32
and you can copy gult32.lib,glut.lib to your project's libs path

Comment: Well, My windows is 10 64-bits, my code: :Blocks is 20.03. I tried this way (i also restarted the computer) and the same happened.

Comment: Please never ever copy libraries into system directories. Place them in the same folder as your exe instead. You will run into all kinds of troubles when two programs require different versions of the same library.